# explain the parameters of cv2.createbackgroundsubtractormog2()

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

Explain the parameters of `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()` in python. so that I can eliminate shadows. MOG2 has capability to detect shadows .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using these kinds of parameters you can eliminate shadows in MOG2. It is better than `BackgroundSubtractorMOG`.

```
fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame, fgmask, 0.005)
```

These parameters generally help to eliminate shadows.

Answer (score 3):

Parameters are defined [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/de1/group__video__motion.html):

E.g.

```
createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history = 500, varThreshold = 16, detectShadows = false)
```

To eliminate shadows, detectShadows should be set to false